# Creating data binding in JS or Direct Binding in TcHmi, Which is Better?

Tags: twincat

Could you please suggest/Comment on **data binding of PLC variable in TcHmi**.

I have designed User Control with 10 parameters, and one drop-down with 5 elements.

Which will be better option:
**1. Using java script:**
Create one User Control and Change the names of parameters and data binding, based on the selection in drop down every time.

**2. Directly binding using **Create data binding** option in TcHmi.**
Create User Controls as as many elements in the drop down and create data binding.

I have a application where both the cases are working absolutely fine.
Just wanted to know others experiences in this regard.

Comment: Hi Kumar. I suggest you read the [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is good that your asking questions here, but they can be improved in general. For example the title of your question is not a question. Secondly you should show what you tried so far.

Comment: Hello @Roald, Thank you for the feedback. i will improve.

Comment: Hello @Roald, could please create TcHmi tag if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I can't create tags yet. I need 1500 rep for that.